# How do you find the first value greater than zero in a column in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I know this is easily done outside of VBA but I want to get proficient with VBA as a beginner.

I have a long column (about 25,000 rows). I need to find the first instance a cell value is greater than zero in that column. Then I need to return the address of that cell to a variable. So far I've been using a loop to no success, any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily do the following:

```
For each c in Range("A1:A25000").Cells
  If c.Value > 0 Then
    firstValue = c.Value
    firstAddress = c.Address
    Exit For
  End If
Next

MsgBox "The first value greater than zero is in cell " & firstAddress & _
       "; - it has value " & firstValue
```

Comment: Happy learning! You might want to update your question with your own attempt - it is considered good to show "what you tried" when you ask a question, as it gives people answering a better idea of how you think, what you know, etc. It makes for better answers.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
Function not_zero() AS String
   Dim lcell as Range

   For Each lcell in Range("$YOUR COLUMN LETTER$1","$YOUR COLUMN LETTER$LAST ROW")
      If CLng(lcell.value) > 0 then
         not_zero = lcell.Address
         Exit For
      End If
   Next lcell
End Function
```

Comment: Might make more sense as a function, since you need to "return an address".

Comment: @Floris you are correct he could also use a `ByRef` Argument but I have changed it to a function since referencing seems like it might be outside his current realm of understanding.